# How to use AnyObject method in zeep library for Python?

Tags: python, xsd, python-3.5, webservice-client

I read in the documentation that it is done like this.

[image]

I did a simple code to try this out and I have the following. (ucmdb is the client)

```
intProp_type = ucmdb.get_element('ns17:IntProp')
intProp = xsd.AnyObject(intProp_type, intProp_type(name = "slots", value = 56 ))
```

And this error comes out.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\zeep-0.12.0-py3.5.egg\zeep\xsd\schema.py", line 71, in get_element
    return schema._elements[qname]
KeyError: <lxml.etree.QName object at 0x000001C314122F08>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ejemplo.py", line 35, in <module>
    main()
  File "ejemplo.py", line 18, in main
    processCIs()
  File "ejemplo.py", line 31, in processCIs
    intProp_type = ucmdb.get_element('ns17:IntProp')
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\zeep-0.12.0-py3.5.egg\zeep\client.py", line 119, in get_element
    return self.wsdl.types.get_element(name)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\zeep-0.12.0-py3.5.egg\zeep\xsd\schema.py", line 81, in get_element
    qname.localname, qname.namespace, known_elements or ' - '))
KeyError: "No element 'IntProp' in namespace http://schemas.hp.com/ucmdb/ui/1/types. Available elements are:  - "
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try it with latest version. Otherwise submit an issue in github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep

Comment: Upgraded to 0.13 but still same problem, issue already submitted.